# Gradle Build failed - AGPBI

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am struggling with a build error that I can't seem to find an answer to.

`AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: attribute \u0027android:guid\u0027 not found.","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Work\\project\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_home.xml","position":{"startLine":4}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}`

It seems like it is repeated for each fragment. (About 30 more times)

I am not sure what to do now.

My logcat returned this

> 06-13 15:24:11.822 28459-28459/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
>   06-13 15:24:11.825 28459-28459/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
>   06-13 15:24:11.964 28459-28459/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
>   06-13 15:24:11.975 28459-28459/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
>   06-13 15:24:11.975 28459-28459/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
>   06-13 15:24:12.354 28478-28478/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
>   06-13 15:24:12.358 28478-28478/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
>   06-13 15:24:12.496 28478-28478/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
>   06-13 15:24:12.508 28478-28478/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
>   06-13 15:24:12.508 28478-28478/? I/AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
>
> ------- beginning of system
>
> 06-13 15:24:27.005 790-12370/? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=875848314, flags=0x1, tag="CMWakeLock", ws=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms}, uid=10011, pid=13763
>       updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Asleep, mWakeLockSummary=0x1
>   06-13 15:24:27.006 790-12370/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Asleep, mUserActivitySummary=0x0, nextTimeout=0 (76973684 ms ago)
>       updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=0, mWakefulness=0, mWakeLockSummary=0x1, mUserActivitySummary=0x0, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
>   06-13 15:24:27.009 790-12370/? D/PowerManagerService: Acquiring suspend blocker "PowerManagerService.WakeLocks".
>   06-13 15:24:27.009 790-12370/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="CMWakeLock", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10011, ownerPid=13763, workSource=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms}
>   06-13 15:24:27.055 13763-28314/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: , App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contextcontroller
>       gai: Long live credential not available.
>           at gaj.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):20)
>           at gaj.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):50)
>           at fyt.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):38)
>           at hpk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):8)
>           at hpk.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):189)
>           at hok.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):2)
>           at hoh.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):17)
>           at hoh.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):6)
>           at cyz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):25)
>           at cyz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):82)
>           at fvp.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):6)
>           at fvo.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):2)
>           at fvo.e(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):6)
>           at fvo.d(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):1)
>           at fvm.b(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):1)
>           at opm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):1)
>           at onz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):3)
>           at drq.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):57)
>           at dmx.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):2)
>           at dmv.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):3)
>           at ouz.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):6)
>           at ovl.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):27)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at pbm.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431))
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   06-13 15:24:27.059 13763-28314/? W/Auth: [GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: BadAuthentication
>   06-13 15:24:27.083 13763-28314/? W/Auth: [GoogleAuthUtil] GoogleAuthUtil
>   06-13 15:24:27.083 13763-28314/? W/AuthSessionAuthenticato: Auth related exception is being ignored: BadAuthentication
>   06-13 15:24:27.100 13763-28314/? E/ctxmgr: [BaseServerTask]Server task (WriteInterestRecordTask) got error statusCode=-1.
>       com.android.volley.VolleyError: Unable to obtain auth token - is the device online?
>           at drq.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):65)
>           at dmx.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):2)
>           at dmv.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):3)
>           at ouz.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):6)
>           at ovl.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431):27)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at pbm.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685006@12.6.85 (020300-197041431))
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   06-13 15:24:27.108 13763-28314/? E/ctxmgr: [SyncServerInterestRecordsOperation]Failed WriteInterestRecord: network status=-1
>   06-13 15:24:27.109 790-805/? D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=875848314 [CMWakeLock], flags=0x0
>   06-13 15:24:27.109 790-805/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="CMWakeLock", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10011, ownerPid=13763, workSource=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms}
>   06-13 15:24:27.109 790-805/? D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Asleep, mWakeLockSummary=0x0
>   06-13 15:24:27.110 790-805/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Asleep, mUserActivitySummary=0x0, nextTimeout=0 (76973788 ms ago)
>       updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=0, mWakefulness=0, mWakeLockSummary=0x0, mUserActivitySummary=0x0, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
>       Releasing suspend blocker "PowerManagerService.WakeLocks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I renamed all of my android:id attributes to 'guid' and because its not an issue that happens often I couldn't find the issue online